# Login form is logging in any user with any password

Tags: php, web, authentication, db2, credentials

I am using php and ibm db2 to create simple login page. However, the code is not providing desired results as expected.

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
}
if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}

elseif (count($errors)==0) {
    //$password = md5($password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $results = db2_exec($db, $query);

    if (db2_num_rows($results)) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Logged in successfully";
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
        header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php', true, 301);
    }else{
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination, Please try again.");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do not write "..is not working...".  Instead, please write what you *expected* and also what *actually* happens.

Comment: And don't store plain passwords in db.

Comment: What error you are getting?  please describe error

Comment: You cannot use db2_num_rows() to get the size of a result-set, that's your mistake. You should test the result of a fetch action.

Comment: @mao ok editied above, thanks

Comment: @u_mulder okay so should I have to use encrypted passwords

Comment: @MayankVadiya I am not getting any error message, but the problem is it is going to homepage/landing page even if the user is not registered in db.

Comment: @mao okay, so can you please tell me what should I use instead?

Comment: @JiaaMemon then just simple print your query result and check condition is ok or not

Comment: What you should use, is probably a tutorial that explains the basics of debugging. Trying to write your own login script, while not even basic debugging skills are present, is just a super bad idea.

Comment: the problem is solved now, thankyou everyone

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [`db2_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-num-rows.php)() to get the number of rows in a result-set.

That `db2_num_rows()` reports the number of inserted/updated/deleted rows impacted by the most recent insert/update/delete statement.

If you want to check for at least one row in the result-set then use one of the [documented methods to fetch a row](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ibm-db2.php) from the result-set. These functions will return true if there is a row otherwise return false when there is no row, or no more rows.

Consider using a prepared statement as per examples, so that the query gets compiled only one time and executed many times.

Answer (score 0):

the query is solved now, thank you everyone!
 I am posting the running code here;

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);

if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
}
if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
}

elseif (count($errors)==0) {
    $password = md5($password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $results = db2_exec($db, $query);

    $row = db2_fetch_assoc($results);

    if ($row['username']== $username && $row['password'] == $password) {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Logged in successfully";

        header('Refresh: 0; URL=index.php', true, 301);
    }else{
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination, Please try again.");
    }
}
```

}